# Как получить список пользователей, которым разрешено sudo?

Tags: linux, sudo

Есть сервер с большим числом системных пользователей, имеющих доступ к нему по SSH.

В рамках задачи по инвентаризации доступов необходимо получить список всех пользователей, которым на этом сервере разрешено становиться рутом через `sudo`.

Понятно, что про единичного пользователя можно посмотреть вывод `id username` на предмет группы wheel (которая из коробки даёт в CentOS возможность становиться рутом через `sudo`), но как бы получить список всех таких пользователей? Понятно, что можно написать цикл, в котором перебрать вывод `id` для всех пользователей системы, но можно ли сделать как-нибудь поизящнее?

Answer (score 5):

универсальный способ получения списка пользователей указанной группы — с помощью программы *getent*, вызванной для базы данных `group` (баз данных много, смотрите в документации: [`$ man getent`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/getent.1.html)):

```
$ getent group название-группы
```

пример вывода:

```
название-группы:x:1000:пользователь1,пользователь2,пользователь3
```

---

чаще всего это просто строка из файла `/etc/group`, которую можно было получить и командой

```
$ grep '^название-группы:' /etc/group
```

но далеко не всегда — ведь существуют разные [механизмы аутентификации](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Directory_services), хранящие данные совсем по-другому.

---

**дополнение**

а по поводу глобального вопроса — получения списка пользователей, которым разрешено выполнение программы *sudo*, короткого, универсального и простого решения, насколько мне известно, нет. надо либо производить синтаксический разбора файлов `/etc/sudoers*`, либо, получив полный список пользователей от всех аутентификационных подсистем (с помощью `$ getent passwd`), анализировать для каждого пользователя вывод команды (не будет работать на старых версиях программы *sudo*):

```
$ sudo -l -U пользователь
```

пример вывода:

```
User пользователь is not allowed to run sudo on ...
```

Answer (score 3):

В CentOS увидеть список всех пользователей, пренадлежащих определённой группе, можно с помощью команды `lid`, например список всех участников группы `wheel` (которым из коробки разрешено выполнять команды от имени и с правами root с помощью `sudo`) можно увидеть так:

```
$ sudo lid -g wheel --
 i.ivanov(uid=1000)
 p.petrov(uid=1001)
 v.pupkin(uid=1008)
```

Надо, однако, понимать, что в sudoers могут быть заданы права "становиться рутом" и для других групп (или для единичных пользователей), так что необходимо также изучить содержимое sudoers (команда `visudo`).

Comment: А про Debian будет продолжение? )

Comment: в Ubuntu 16.04 (первое Debian-подобное, что нашёл) из коробки `lid` вообще нет. обязательно напишу, как разберусь =)

Comment: Вообще-то есть стандартная POSIX команда `getent`.